# How to extract a value from a tensor as int in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

This question is with respect to accessing individual elements in a tensor, say [1,2,3]. I need to access the inner element [1]. Since I am calling another api library which is not from tensorflow. This api needs an int value as an argument.I am having problems putting [1] into that api as [1] is shown as a tensor, instead of an int. Is there a way to convert a single tensor like [1] into an int 1?

Comment: Can you please paste the code you have which is used to create the tensor you mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a session, load/initialize variables then run the session.

```
# build graph
target_tensor = bigger_tensor[1, 2]  # whichever index you want
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  # or load from file
    target_value = sess.run(target_tensor)  #may need a feed_dict if your model uses placeholders
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not know whether it is exactly the method I want, as I am adding a term to the loss function in tensorflow, but the extra term has to be calculated by an outside package. I want it to be calculated within session, but I will give this method a try. Thank you very much.

Comment: If your goal is to add a custom op to the loss function in the middle of a training step, you may want to try another alternative. `sess.run()` is only really useful for fetching the outputs of the step, not for mixing TensorFlow and non-TensorFlow code in the same step. You might want to look into expressing your computation using TensorFlow operators first, or using a `tf.py_func` if that doesn't work. It's hard to say what is the right thing to do without more details.